# Missing trailing slash apache wordpress ssl

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl

I bought an SSL from comodo, and i used HTTP file auth for the validation process.
placed the .txt file in .well-known/pki-validation/  folder, but the validation is failing as the url leads to [www.example.com.well-known/pki-validation/file.txt](http://www.example.com.well-known/pki-validation/file.txt) with the trailing slash missing.
attempted many htaccess codes but its not working. also tried to change the url by adding a trailing slash at the end of the url in wordpress settings but no luck.

any fixes is highly appreciated.